# Show that $\tan (nx) \neq 0$

Tags: calculus

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

> Show that
>
> $$\tan (nx) \neq 0$$
>
> where $n$ is a positive integer and $\tan x=\frac{3}{2}, (0<x<\frac{π}{2})$

I tried to solve this problem but I can't

I find $\tan 2x=-\frac{12}{5}, \tan 3x=-\frac{9}{46} $

Comment: $\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$, and for a fraction to be zero....

Comment: @Henrik: That's the easy part! Now you have to show that $\sin nx \ne 0$ if $\tan x = \frac32$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We just need to prove that
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\,\arctan\frac{3}{2}\not\in\mathbb{Q},\tag{1}$$
or that there is no $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that:
$$ \left(\frac{1+\frac{3}{2}i}{\sqrt{\frac{13}{4}}}\right)^{2n}=\left(\frac{2+3i}{2-3i}\right)^{n} = 1. \tag{2}$$
However, that is trivial, by considering that $\tan x=\frac{3}{2}$ implies $\cos x=\pm\frac{2}{\sqrt{13}}$, that is an algebraic number over $\mathbb{Q}$ with degree $2$. On the other hand, $x=2\pi\cdot\frac{p}{q}$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$ implies that $\cos x$ is an algebraic number over $\mathbb{Q}$ with degree $\frac{\varphi(q)}{2}$, so $\varphi(q)=4$ gives $q\in\{5,8,10,12\}$ and we have just a finite number of cases to check to prove $(1)$ - for instance, $13$ is not a divisor of the discriminant of $\Phi_5(x),\Phi_8(x),\Phi_{10}(x)$ or $\Phi_{12}(x)$ (cyclotomic polynomials).

Comment: Great answer, I would have thought the solution would have been more simple

Comment: @RoryDaulton: I removed that part since I think that to consider the degree of $\cos x$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is the most natural approach to prove the irrationality of $\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\frac{3}{2}$. The key point is just that $\varphi(13)$ is (too) big, since $13$ is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$.